# How to remove first attempt of failed test cases from extent report when using RetryAnalyzer

Tags: testng, extentreports

I am using IretryAnalyzer to repeat the failed test cases. But have a problem when it shows in extent report it repeats the test cases which are failed. How to show only the final result of test case in extent report and remove the repeated ones in selenium testNG. I have used the following code but it did not work.

```
Set<ITestResult> failedTests = context.getFailedTests().getAllResults();
        for (ITestResult temp : failedTests) {
            ITestNGMethod method = temp.getMethod();
            if (context.getFailedTests().getResults(method).size() > 1) {
                result.getTestContext().getFailedTests().removeResult(result.getMethod());
                extent.removeTest(this.test);
            } else {
                if (context.getPassedTests().getResults(method).size() > 0) {
                    result.getTestContext().getFailedTests().removeResult(result.getMethod());
                    extent.removeTest(this.test);
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just simply you can remove this skipped test

```
@AfterMethod(alwaysRun = true)
    public void getResult(ITestResult result) throws IOException {
        if (result.getStatus() == ITestResult.FAILURE) {
            
           if(result.wasRetried()){
               getTest().skip("Retried"); //Do your operation
           }else {
               //Do your operation
           }
        } else if (result.getStatus() == ITestResult.SUCCESS) {
          
        } else if (result.getStatus() == ITestResult.SKIP) {
         
        }
    }
```

Here when attempts are failed and retried I checked using **wasRetried()** and make it skip or failed

Answer (score 0):

you can remove your ExtentTest from ExtentReport, just make sure don't flush your ExtentReports before removing ExtentTest.

```java
public void removeCurrentTest(final ExtentReports reports, final ExtentTest extentTest) {
        reports.removeTest(extentTest);
}
```

If it doesn't work, update your lib to the last version (5.0 or later should work)